# Was Nityananda Mahaprabhu a non-vegeterian?

Tags: history, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya-bhagavata

Mahaprabhu Nitayananda took sannyasa at an early age. As per the Sri Sri Chaitanya-Bhagavata, the first authentic biography of Sri Chaitanya by Srila Vrindavana Das Thakura, Sri Advaita Acharya says Nityananda Mahaprabhu lovingly:

> *matsya khay mansa khay kemata sannyasi/...tare boli sannyasi ye kichu naahi chhay/bolaye sannyasi dine tinbar khay//* (**Madhya-KhaNda, Chapter 24**).
>
> Meaning : **You eat fish! You eat meat! How are you a sannyasin? A sannyasin should eat food once in a day, but you claim to be one and eat thrice.**

Was Mahaprabhu Nityananda a non-vegeterian?

Answer (score 1):

**Srila Bhaktisiddhanta Goswami Maharaja's commentary on this verse:**

> In the course of argument and counter-argument, Śrī Advaita Prabhu
> became very angry and said,

> “Your behavior is similar to that of a dārī
> sannyāsī who eats fish and meat and who brags that he has given up the
> dress of a householder and become naked. You are just like the Tantric
> sannyāsīs who are envious of the Vaiṣṇavas, who are attached to sense
> gratification, who are followers of Śākta philosophy, and who try to
> protect their reputation as sannyāsīs by indulging in pañca-makāra
> [Pañca-makāra refers to māṁsa, madya, matsya, mahila, and maithuna—
> meat, wine, fish, women, and sex]. Whimsical behavior can never be the characteristic of a sannyāsī under the shelter of the Vedas.”

> After reading these statements, foolish people should not consider Śrī
> Baladeva-Śrī Nityānanda Prabhu as fallen from sannyāsa and proper
> behavior. It should be known that one who exposes his natural foolishness
> by failing to understand the actual purport of Advaita’s statements is
> unqualified to understand the characteristics of Nityānanda Prabhu. These
> sarcastic or disguised as blasphemous statements of Śrī Advaita are
> simply a ploy to increase the sinful propensities of those who eat fish and
> meat. Those not understanding the purport of these words who are most
> unfortunate and bereft of intelligence take shelter of worldly sinful
> activities and traverse the path to hell. Those who are easily influenced
> by the word jugglery of others can never become intelligent devotees of
> Kṛṣṇa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is from Chaitanya Bhagavata, Madhya Khanda, Chapter 24, text 89.  The link for english translation :- https://archive.org/details/CBMadhya/page/n1920/mode/2up. The link for its original bengali text and commentary by Srila Bhaktisiddhanta Sarasvati :- https://archive.org/details/CBBSSTMadhya/CB-BSST-Madhya-24/page/n5/mode/2up

Comment: The response is offensive to people of a different opinion, it is ad hominem. In fact, I'd be interested in the answer too. In the book Chaitanya: A Life and Legacy by Professor Amiya P. Sen, I also learnt that according to hagiographies, Nityananda not only ate meat but also drank alcohol, wore expensive jewellery. Unfortunately, the book is not written in a scholarly manner, it is more of a narrative and does not contain a direct reference to this claim.